# Synology Surveillance Web API Help. Grab Snapshot?

Tags: json, http, synology

How can I grab a "snapshot" from the Surveillance Station Web API? What I would like to do is grab a snapshot and feed it to a web page.

Not very familiar with how the Web API works for Synology Surveillance Station (I am a newbie at programming in general). I have tried reading through the help. The web API help can be found here. [Surveillance Station Web API](https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/DeveloperGuide/Surveillance_Station_Web_API_v2.0.pdf)

When I enter this into a browser I am expecting to get a snapshot JPG back

```
http://MyNASip:5000/webapi/entry.cgi?camStm=1&version="8"&cameraId=1&api="SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera"&preview=true&method="GetSnapshot"
```

Am I understanding this right?

Instead I get this in the browser

```
{"error":{"code":105},"success":false}
```

And I get the following in the /var/log/messages

```
2018-02-05T13:15:03-06:00 DS215j synoscgi_SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera_8_GetSnapshot[15020]: group_is_admin_group_member_by_uid.c:14 SYNOUserGetByUID(4294967295) failed [0x1D00 user_get_by_uid.c:129
```

Is the an authentication issue?

Comment: Page 16 of the API says error 105 is "Insufficient user privilege". Do you first make a call to the login method as described on page 21?

Comment: No. I have not and I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I have no knowledge of Synology products, I'm just looking at the API you linked to.  Following the workflow shown on page 14 you should be able to accomplish what you want.  This may help: whenever you see `GET /webapi/...` you can change that to `http://MyNASip:5000/webapi/...` and send the request using your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will see what I can do.

Comment: @Paul That seemed to work. Add it as a reply and I will make it answered. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Done, thanks.  Maybe you can update your question with the auth request you sent (redacting username/password of course) as it may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 16 of the API says error 105 is "Insufficient user privilege". Following the workflow shown on page 14 you should be able to accomplish what you want. Try first making a call to the login method (page 21) then requesting the snapshot.

This may help: whenever you see `GET /webapi/...` you can change that to `http://MyNASip:5000/webapi/...` and send the request using your browser.

Answer (score 3):

The code to grab a snaphots must get the PATH, CAMERA PATH and an SID from the api before accessing a snapshot.
Here is an extract of my code (see below)

```
$user = "xxxxxxx";  // Synology username with rights to Surveillance station 
$pass = "xxxxxxx";  // Password of the user entered above 
$ip = "192.168.xxxxxx";  // IP-Adress of your Synology-NAS 
$port = "5000";  // default port of Surveillance Station 
$http = "http"; // Change to https if you use a secure connection 
$cameraID = xx;
$cameraStream = xx];
$vCamera = 7; //Version API SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera
$vAuth = ""; 
if ($cameraStream == NULL) { 
    $cameraStream = "0"; 
} 
//Get SYNO.API.Auth Path (recommended by Synology for further update)
    $json = file_get_contents($http.'://'.$ip.':'.$port.'/webapi/query.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Info&method=Query&version=1&query=SYNO.API.Auth');
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    $AuthPath = $obj->data->{'SYNO.API.Auth'}->path;
// Authenticate with Synology Surveillance Station WebAPI and get our SID 
    $json = file_get_contents($http.'://'.$ip.':'.$port.'/webapi/'.$AuthPath.'?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=Login&version=6&account='.$user.'&passwd='.$pass.'&session=SurveillanceStation&format=sid'); 
    $obj = json_decode($json); 
//Check if auth ok
if($obj->success != "true"){
    echo "error";
    exit();
}else{
//authentification successful
    $sid = $obj->data->sid;

//Get SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera path (recommended by Synology for further update)
        $json = file_get_contents($http.'://'.$ip.':'.$port.'/webapi/query.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Info&method=Query&version=1&query=SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera');
        $obj = json_decode($json);
        $CamPath = $obj->data->{'SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera'}->path;

// Get Snapshot
if ($cameraID != NULL) { 
        // Setting the correct header so the PHP file will be recognised as a JPEG file 
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
        // Read the contents of the snapshot and output it directly without putting it in memory first 
        readfile($http.'://'.$ip.':'.$port.'/webapi/'.$CamPath.'?camStm='.$cameraStream.'&version='.$vCamera.'&cameraId='.$cameraID.'&api=SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera&preview=true&method=GetSnapshot&_sid='.$sid); 
}
```

This is an extract of the php script that I wrote to interface all the calls to the synology Surveillance Station API.
You can grab snapshots, mjpeg, start stop, send mails etc..

here it is: https://github.com/sjauquet/YAPUSS

The code is very simple, feel free to find inspirations.

Comment: This is not an answer to the specific problem, but a comment hinting in a direction to solve it. Please delete answer and post as comment.

Comment: Ok, well, I'm new as a poster here, but when I trien to comment, the sytem says that I must have 50 reputation to post a comment ...

Comment: The post a real answer in which you address OP’s question and specifically instruct how to 1) incorporate the repo in OP’s project and 2) use the repo to solve the question with a couple of examples.

Comment: Helpful answer, thanks @sebcbien for posting the steps needed to make this work. Particularly helpful to anyone doing this from PHP but generally readable by anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cookielib, urllib2

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
nas =  'url.synology.me'
dsm_url = 'https://'+nas+':8080'
username = 'user'
password = 'password'

opener.addheaders = [
        ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.11) Gecko/20101012 Firefox/3.6.11'),
            ]
url1=dsm_url+'/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=Login&version=1&account='+username+'&passwd='+password+'&session=SurveillanceStation&format=sid'
url3=dsm_url+'/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera&method=GetSnapshot&version=1&cameraId=2&preview=true'
url4=dsm_url+'/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=Logout&version=1&account='+username+'&passwd='+password+'&session=SurveillanceStation'

opener.open(url1)

stream=opener.open(url3)
with open ('image.jpg','w') as f1: f1.write(stream.read())
opener.open(url4)
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old thread, but I just had a similar problem and figured out what was going on. The Surveillance Station application has its own user accounts that are separate from the NAS user accounts. Log in to Surveillance Station, and make sure you have a user set up there.